# My Tailwind classes are not being used in Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I installed Tailwind CSS, but the classes are not working for me.

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
    module.exports = {
      content: ["./pages/*.{html,js,jsx}", "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    };
```

**postcss.config**

```js
    module.exports = {
      plugins: {
        "postcss-import": {},
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
      },
    };
```

**global.css**

```css
    @import "tailwindcss/base"; /* I tried @tailwind as well */
    
    @import "tailwindcss/components";
    
    @import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

**package.json**

```json
    {
      "name": "events-blog",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@next/font": "13.1.2",
        "next": "13.1.2",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
        "postcss": "^8.4.21",
        "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
      }
    }
```

[image: Folder structure]

I can not understand what the problem is. It seems to not be including Tailwind, which is confusing.

Comment: First, yes it is `@tailwind`. Second, can you show what you have inside src and pages ? In my next project I don't have src and for the pages in tailwind config I have : `./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}`. And I didn't need `postcss-import`

Comment: I had the same problem and I restarted the server, then it worked, ( make sure you have config correctly )

Answer (score 0):

This is the step by step TailwindCSS configuration for NextJS :

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Add the paths to all of your template files in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
 
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Add the @tailwind directives for each Tailwind’s layers to your globals.css file.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Run your build process with npm run dev.

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the step you are missing (or at least not showing in your post) is importing the global.css file in some high level component.  Since this is a Next app using the page router, this would probably be pages/_app.jsx).

pages/_app.jsx:

```
import '../../styles/global.css'

const App = () => {/* etc */}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
    @import "tailwindcss/base";
    @import "tailwindcss/components";
    @import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

to

```
    @import "tailwind/base"; 
    @import "tailwind/components";
    @import "tailwind/utilities";
```

And make sure that `"./pages/*.{html,js,jsx}", "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"` these are the places where you want your tailwind to work.

Anything outside this scope `tailwind-css` wont work.